# libjli.so "No such file or directory" while trying to run Arduno IDE

Tags: java, arduino, ubuntu-16.04

I downloaded Arduino IDE and extracted it. When trying to run it:

```
./arduino
```

It throws up an error:

```
/opt/arduino-1.6.9/java/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

But still the same error. No change if I use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
rm /usr/bin/java
update-alternatives --config java
```

Run as `sudo` if required.

Comment: After running the second command, I am getting:

    There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.

    update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java because link group java is broken

And still the same error when trying to run arduino

Comment: Can you please post the output of `strace -f java -version`?

Comment: It is too long, more than 200k characters, cant post here.

Comment: On pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sythD16e

Comment: I still think it is a link problem. Try this `rm -rf /usr/bin/java` and `ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java`. Next time while posting comments, please [format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24794) it accordingly. It's difficult to read the sys output on your previous comment.

Comment: No luck, it is still throwing up the same error when I try to run.

Comment: Do you see `libjli.so` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/tls/x86_64/libjli.so`? If not put it there, or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include where `libjli.so` is.

Comment: On running `$ locate libjli.so`, I get: 
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so`. Added the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. `sudo ldconfig`. Now when I try to run again, `Error: could not find libjava.so` and `Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`. So I also added the location of file mentioned in the first error message to `LD...`. Still getting the two error messages. But `libjli.so` seems to have bee found.

Comment: What do you get for `which java`? If `/usr/bin/java` what does it point to?

Comment: I completely removed java and installed openjdk 9. Now it points to `/etc/alternatives/java`, before it was pointing to some other location (I don't remember). And the program runs fine. Thanks a lot @Michael for your help!

Comment: Sure, glad to hear you got it working.